# How do I programmatically add a "Load More" button?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to add the "Load More" button in the block view programmatically.

Initially, I am loading the 9 contents but when clicking on the button next 9 contents should load from view.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can try one of these two modules:

- [Views infinite scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll)

  > Views infinite scroll allows you to load and display pages of any view inline, using AJAX (this has been called infinite scrolling, load more, autopaging, endless pages and more). The pager can be triggered with the press of a button or automatically as the user scrolls to the bottom of the view's content.
- [Views load more](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more)

  > Yes, this is indeed, Yet another load more pager for views.
  >
  > This module has some very key differences then the other load more module.
  >
  > - Provide ajax/no-ajax views load more
  > - Works with views default ajax implementation, no hacks (check/uncheck ajax)
  > - Supports the Waypoints module for loading on various points, Such as when the scroller is visable on the page.
  > - Supports the Fade effect when loading new content